# Is there a formal term for the sequence of all products of an alphabet from length m..n?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, permutations, terminology

> I have been doing some work which required me to iterate through all possible arrangements of digits in a given base for tuples of length $0..n$ and (having already achieved my task), I wanted to get some terminology straight to help me research further if anyone else has solved the task in a different way.

Suppose we have an alphabet consisting of all the digits in a given base: $\alpha = (0, 1, 2)$ (base-3 is used here as an example)

A sequence $S$ consisting of the product of $\alpha$ with itself $k$ many times, from $m..n$ with $m = 0$ and $n = 3$ is thus:

$$
S = ((), (0), (1), (2), (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (2, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 0, 2), (2, 1, 0), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 0), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2))
$$

Or, by clumsily adapting set-builder notation into *sequence-builder notation*: $S = ( \alpha^k\ \|\ m \leq k \leq n)$

> Note that here, $\alpha^x$ is defined to work in the same way as the *Cartesian Product* does for set theory, being a convenient way to generate every possible arrangement of digits in the given base, $k$ many times.

###### What is the formal mathematical name for the sequence $S$, as I have described it here?

*Note that $n$ can go on to infinity, but $m$ is fixed.*

I want to know because I have devised a method for bijectively converting to and from integers and tuples within $S$ (the integer corresponds to the tuple's index within $S$), but without needing to pre-compute $S$, which is handy for large alphabets and tuple-lengths.

I want to know if there is formal terminology for this kind of thing because I want to research if there are any existing methods besides my own for doing this, but my previous research had me looking up permutations and combinations, which I now know to be quite different to the thing I have thus described.

Comment: Probably doesn't have a general name. The number of elements is $\frac{b^{n+1}-b^m}{b-1},$ where $b$ is the base.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes, that was one of the formulæ I came up with when creating the function to map int -> tuples from this sequence

Comment: The terminology I'd probably reach for is "tuples of length $r\in[m,n]$".

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to say $S^{\lt n}$ or (if $m \gt 0$) $S^{\lt n} \setminus S^{\lt m}$.

Comment: Thanks, this seems shorter than what I currently have. By the way, I forgot to mention in the question that $n$ doesn't have to be bounded (the sequence of integers and tuples goes on forever as $n$ goes to infinity). Does that effect the notation?

Comment: Just to clarify, this notation in the power, means to concatenate all sequences produced by raising $S$ to every power from $0..n$? That's quite neat!

Comment: Presumably, in that case it would be $S^{<\infty}$?

Comment: There is a standard notation for all finite sequences (of any length).  It's $S^{\lt \omega}$.